# Entity Framework query returning wrong results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I usually don’t ask question about my own errors or problems, but right now I’m stuck.

My problem is with result from EF LinQ query. It SHOULD work, but it does not. The numbers returned are waaay out (like 3.000.000 %)

So, to put the question in context: imagine you have an organization, devised into directions. Each person is in one direction and called “resource”.

Each person works on “Projects”.

The pacification is for a project is saved by intervals ( Ex : from day 0 to day 11, it’s 1 hour/day)

Now, we want ALL resources (persons), grouped by direction with their total time for a period.

My request is :

```
var result = from r in com.Ressources
             where
             ids.Contains(r.Id)
             && (from p in r.Projects
                 where p.StartDate <= dates.To && p.EndDate >= dates.From
                 select p).Count() > 0
             group r by r.Direction into groups
             orderby groups.Key.DirectionName
             select new
             {
                 Id = groups.Key.Id,
                 DirectionName = groups.Key.DirectionName,
                 Responsable = groups.Key.Responsable.Prenom + " " + groups.Key.Responsable.Nom,
                 Ressources = from pr in groups
                              let totalpl = (double?)
                                            (from planif in pr.Planification
                                              let startOffset = JayaModelContainer.GetWorksDaysCount(planif.Project.StartDate, dates.From)
                                              let endOffset = JayaModelContainer.GetWorksDaysCount(planif.Project.StartDate, dates.To)
                                              where
                                              planif.FromProjectDay <= endOffset && planif.ToProjectDay >= startOffset
                                              let start = planif.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? startOffset : planif.FromProjectDay
                                              let end = planif.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? endOffset : planif.ToProjectDay
                                              select (end - start + 1) * planif.Amount).Sum()
                              let totalrl = (double?)
                                            (from reel in com.RealTimes
                                              let startOffset = JayaModelContainer.GetWorksDaysCount(reel.Project.StartDate, dates.From)
                                              let endOffset = JayaModelContainer.GetWorksDaysCount(reel.Project.StartDate, dates.To)
                                              where reel.TimeSheet.Ressource.Id == pr.Id &&
                                                reel.FromProjectDay <= endOffset && reel.ToProjectDay >= startOffset
                                              let start = reel.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? startOffset : reel.FromProjectDay
                                              let end = reel.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? endOffset : reel.ToProjectDay
                                              select (end - start + 1) * reel.Amount).Sum()           
                              orderby pr.Prenom, pr.Nom
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = pr.Id,
                                  FirstName = pr.Prenom,
                                  LastName = pr.Nom,
                                  Occupation = pr.Occupation.Name,
                                  TotalPlanifs = totalpl,
                                  TotalReels = totalrl,
                                  PlannifCapacity = totalpl / maxCapacity,
                                  ReelCapacity = totalrl / maxCapacity
                              }
             };
```

But for some reason, the numbers returned are waaay off (Like 9546 % or 147.000 hours a month)

Any idea where my error come from ?

I think it’s in the query but can not find where

Thanks

EDIT : In case you wonder, (double?) is there for a reason. If there is no records in the table, the “sum” will crash with “Unable to cast “null” into double”. This little trick allow to do all expressions on null values

EDIT2 : SOLVED

Found my error!

Inversed values in these 4 lignes  :

```
let start = planif.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? startOffset : planif.FromProjectDay
let end = planif.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? endOffset : planif.ToProjectDay
let start = reel.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? startOffset : reel.FromProjectDay
let end = reel.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? endOffset : reel.ToProjectDay
```

These lines should be:

```
let start = planif.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? planif.FromProjectDay : startOffset
let end = planif.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? planif.ToProjectDay : endOffset
let start = reel.FromProjectDay > startOffset ? reel.FromProjectDay : startOffset
let end = reel.ToProjectDay <= endOffset ? reel.ToProjectDay : endOffset
```

Works perfectly now !

Comment: p.StartDate <= dates.To && p.EndDate >= dates.From is this right? from and to seems to be in wrong comparison

Comment: Yes actually. I take all project active during the period. For this to be true, the project must start before the end date and finish after start date.